# Invalid Foreign Key Relationship when referring to custom object text field

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

Hopefully this is a simple one, but I'm pretty stumped. Basically, I'm editing a text field of a custom object. However, it seems I get a Invalid Foreign Key Relationship error when I try and check whether the field is null:

Here's the code that throws the exception:

```
for(Account a: listOfAccounts{
    for(object__c o: listOfObjects){
        if(!o.Name.isBlank()){
             o.Name.replace(a.textField__c, '');
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why, since this works:

```
for(Account a: listOfAccounts{
    for(object__c o: listOfObjects){     
        o.Name.replace(a.textField__c, '');
    }
}
```

However, this code throws a null pointer exception if o.Name is null

Comment: Well, I narrowed it down to using the .isBlank() method... Still now sure why it's throwing an error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isBlank is a **static** method of the String class. You want:

```
if(!String.isBlank(o.Name)){
         o.Name.replace(a.textField__c, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you have the 'Is Not Blank' set up

```
!o.Name.isBlank()
```

Should be

```
NOT(ISBLANK(o.Name))
```

Comment: Interesting... The documentation shows otherwise:  https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isBlank. I think you might be thinking setting up formulas in SFDC?

Comment: @Danomyte66 Yeah sorry about that, I've been deep in with workflows and they validate based on the formula's.

Speaking of which, you could probably accomplish this same thing with a workflow rule.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is !String.isEmpty(o.Name) (as it states in the documentation :/)

Comment: isEmpty is not the same as isBlank. isBlank evaluates if all characters in the string are whitespace.